# to determine if an azimuth is between two given azimuths

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra

Azimuth is the angle a line makes between North pole/axis and itself. They can vary from 0 degree to 360 if rotated in a circular path. Lets say we have two such azimuths, Alpha and Beta. We wish to determine of another azimuth ,say Gamma, falls between two azimuths alpha and beta.

Can someone please help me out with a simple algorithm or formula to be used in excel to determine if the line corresponding to gamma is between two lines corresponding to alpha and beta. gamma can assume different values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Gamma is between two lines corresponding to alpha and beta when both expressions:

```
ag = atan2(cos(a)*sin(g)-sin(a)*cos(g), cos(a)*cos(g)+sin(a)*sin(g))
gb = atan2(cos(g)*sin(b)-sin(g)*cos(b), cos(g)*cos(b)+sin(g)*sin(b))
```

- have the same sign,
 - (*probably important - both values lie in range [0..Pi] or [-Pi..0]*),
 - and their sum is equal to

```
ab = atan2(cos(a)*sin(b)-sin(a)*cos(b), cos(a)*cos(b)+sin(a)*sin(b))
```

These expressions are angles between azimuths, taking into account possible angle wrapping around 360

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct. When I toyed around with this in excel I found that when the angle between a and b was 90degrees any g that was between a and b showed a positive ag and a positive gb. A ag and gb were both negative in some cases where g was not in between a and b. I could not find any cases where ag and gb were both negative when g was in between a and b.

Comment: @caps Example: `a=0,b=Pi/2,g=Pi/4. ag=atan2(0.707,0.707)=Pi/4; gb=atan2(-0.707,0.707)= - Pi/4`

Comment: with a=0, b=90, g=45 (all converted to Radians), I get ag=45, gb=45, ab=0 (after converting back from Radians)

Comment: Also, in your example, ag and gb have different signs, even though Pi/4 is between 0 and Pi/2, yet this answer says they should have the same sign if g is between a and b.

Comment: Hmm, I have to recheck quick calculations... You are true - `gb=atan2(0.707,0.707)=Pi/4`